# Finalbuilder 8 fails to load Delphi 10 Seattle project file

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, finalbuilder

Since we upgraded finalbuilder to version 8, and Delphi to version 10 Seattle, we are getting error messages when trying to edit actiom properties in our finalbuilder project.

> Failed to load MSBuild project file:
>       Syste.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot locate file or assembly Finalbuilder.MSBuild.Tasks, Version 8.0.0.0

Is this caused by finalbuilder missing something or by delphi .pproj files that are changed in Delphi 10 Seattle and cannot be read anymore by Finalbuilder?

Edit:
Finalbuilder ticket http://support.finalbuilder.com/default.asp?146614_2g7d2d4os04iv4qm

Comment: Did you contact the vendor for support?

Comment: @david hefferman Yes I did (http://support.finalbuilder.com/default.asp?146614_2g7d2d4os04iv4qm), but no solution from them (yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalbuilder has confirmed the issue and fixed it in the latest release 8.0.0.1403